# Force Unix line endings for a partition in Notepad++

Tags: linux, partitioning, unix, notepad++, sshfs

I've a Linux partition mounted using Web Drive on a Windows PC. It uses the same Drive letter all the time. Whenever I create a empty new text file and then open it with Notepad++, it starts using Windows line endings.

Is there any way to force Linux line endings on a specific partition in Notepad++?

Comment: This isn't really the solution you're seeking, which I understand from your question, but may want to get familiar with ALT-E, E, U

Comment: I tried connecting default EOL to a Session, but it doesn't seem possible. You can change default EOL by going to Settings, Preferences, New Document, Format or by editing your config.xml file directly http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files#NewDocDefaultSettings

Comment: Thanks @Kennah. I finally created this using your suggestion http://superuser.com/a/1019631/398328

Answer (score 1):

I'm finally able to do this, with a simple AutoHotKey script. First assign a keyboard shortcut to "Convert to Unix Line Ending" in "Shortcut Mapper" (It should be around S.No 153)

```
#IfWinActive, G:\ ahk_class Notepad++
    ^s::Send ^!j^s
#IfWinActive
```

First lines checks if current windows is notepad++ and opened file is from `G:\` partition (Notepad++ set current file path as title)

Second line capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and then send first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Notepad++ keyboard shortcut to change line ending to Unix), and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to finally save it)

Comment: I use Autohotkey, and that never occurred to me. Much appreciated.